# Angular 4 Refresh section of page only

Tags: angular, redirect, url-routing, page-refresh

Hi community I have a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNoGFP6fva4SYmcspoOj?p=preview) where I have implemented this flow:

Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNoGFP6fva4SYmcspoOj?p=preview): I solved but header component gets called each time and I have to put my header component in each html is there a better way to do it?

1. Login
2. Show list of countries (User info on top)
3. Click on one of the  countries and show details about it (Problem is here)
4. Go back to list

I need to refresh only the section of the countries list, but in my plunker you can see the whole page is refreshing I want to keep the user info on top (static).

I have little experience.
Thanks a lot!

```
@Component({
selector : 'login',
template: `
<input type="text" value="james">
<input type="password" value="123">
<button (click)="logIn()">Login</button>
`
})
class LoginComponent {
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router) { }

    logIn () {
        //LOGIN LOGIC
        this.router.navigate(['/base']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this! I had found the way to do it but it wasn't the correct aproach. Here is the solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/pNoGFP6fva4SYmcspoOj?p=preview

I used children components in the routing configuration and change the way navigations are done:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/base',  { outlets: { mod : ['countrydetail', country_id ] } } ]);
```

where:

- /base is the origin component, where the navigation is starting.
- mod is the outlet name (children in app.routing)
- countrydetail the child component name
- country_id: a parameter

Answer (score 0):

The `router-outlet` shows the content of the route.
That means you have to place your user template code above the `router-outlet` so it wone be affected by your route navigation...

```
<label>User: Mr. James</label> 
  <label>Role: Administrator</label>
  <hr>
<router-outlet>
```

Comment: I already have that tag in the root component. Putting router outlet there doesnt show the countries list.

Answer (score 0):

first create common header component and render your components using `routerLink` and `router.navigate`

angular doc have good example
https://angular.io/guide/router

plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ApjJkNwS6hfS56DjL7vt?p=preview

Comment: I managed to do it like this (http://plnkr.co/edit/pNoGFP6fva4SYmcspoOj?p=preview) but the header component gets called each time and I don't need that is there another way?